# Prove that $2x^3+5x^2+6x+1\equiv 0$ mod $7$ has 3 solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $2x^3+5x^2+6x+1\equiv 0$ mod $7$ has 3 solutions.

So I think I need to show that $f(x)\mid x^7-x$

But I don't really understand what that means.

So I have $x^7-x=f(x)g(x)+r(x)$ and I need to show $r(x)=0$

But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A degree $n$ polynomial over a field has at most $n$ solutions in that field. In our case we have a degree 3 polynomial $f(x)$ and we are working over the field $\mathbb{F}_7$. Since our field is finite, we can just go through each element in the field and see if it is a solution. By inspection we see that $x = 1, 2, 5$ are solutions so it in fact has exactly 3 solutions mod 7. This means that if we take $(x-1)(x-2)(x-5)$ and expand this out and take all coefficients mod 7 we'll get back a multiple of the original polynomial, in this case $f(x) = 2(x-1)(x-2)(x-5)$ mod 7.

We know that $x^7 - x$ factors as the product $\Pi_{i = 0}^6 (x-i)$ so $x^7 - x = f(x)*[4x(x-3)(x-4)(x-6)]$ mod 7 (4 is the inverse of 2 mod 7).

Comment: Is it enough to know that the degree $3$ divides $6$? Or is that only true for polynomials $x^d-1\equiv 0$ mod $p$?

Comment: it is not enough. There exist degree 3 polynomials mod 7 which don't have any roots (have you learned about irreducible polynomials?), for example x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0 mod 7

Answer (score 4):

Working with coefficients/numbers from $\mathbb{F}_7$, we have
$$\begin{align}2 x^3 + 5 x^2 + 6x + 1 
& \equiv 2x^3 - 2x^2 - x + 1\\
& \equiv (2x^2 - 1)(x-1)\\ 
&\equiv 2(x^2 - 4)(x-1)\\ & \equiv 2(x-1)(x-2)(x+2)\end{align}$$
The cubic polynomial is a product of 3 linear factors with 3 roots, $1$, $2$, and $5 \equiv -2$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

$5\equiv -2 \pmod 7$ and $6 \equiv -1\pmod 7$ so

$2x^3+5x^2 + 6x + 1 \equiv 2x^2 - 2x^2 - x +1\equiv 2x^2(x-1)-(x-1)=(2x^2-1)(x-1)$

It isn't easy to immediately see how $2x^2-1$ can factor (or if it can) but $2x^2 - 1 \equiv 2x^2 + 6\equiv 2(x^2 +3)$ so if we can find $-k^2 \equiv 3\pmod 7$ we can have a difference of squares.

$3 \equiv -4.. $ and ... that was quick.

So $2x^3+5x^2 + 6x + 1\equiv (2x^2-1)(x-1)$

$\equiv 2(x^2+3)(x-1)\equiv 2(x^2 -4)(x-1)$

$\equiv 2(x+2)(x-2)(x-1)$.

So there are three solutions to $2(x+2)(x-2)(x-1)$.  Then are $x\equiv 1\pmod 7$, $x\equiv 2\pmod 7$ and $x\equiv -2 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.